# ADB- Cannot get the Path variable to work for ADB

Tags: adb, windows, command-line

I am unable to execute ADB from CMD after adding it to the Path Variable. I am able to launch it from the folder when I open a Command Prompt there. But I am unable to launch ADB straight from CMD without first navigating to it.

My Path Variable:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin; E:\Programs\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

My SDK path is at the end. How am I able to correct this so that I can launch ADB without first navigating to its folder.

**Edit:** The program is only my portable hard drive if this helps at all at diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Removed my Path Variable as I was getting nowhere, and instead I put the contents of the platforms-tools folder at the root directory of where my CMD opens in, which is my user folder. I am now able to run ADB from the default CMD location, although this isn't an ideal and thorough solution that can be used were every I open the CMD prompt on my computer, it is still a solution until I can fix this path variable problem.

**Edit:** It Seems that I had a space after this `;` It isn't ment to have a space between `;`and the begin of the address